# np.array行列の２乗を求めたい。

Tags: python, numpy, array

以下の np.array()で作成した行列があります（どのように作成したかは省略し、行列の中身だけ書いています）。

```py
   a = [-11007  -9748  -7942  -6331  -5511  -5508  -5421  -4330  -3289  -1807]
```

この行列の各要素の２乗を求めたいのですが、いくつか方法を試しても
以下の値が返ってきます。

```py
    [-22015  -3696  29732 -26471  27953  -5104  27113   5604   4081 -11551]
```

"`**`" "`pow()`" "`np.power()`" は試しました。
Jupyter Notebookを使用しています。
解決策をご教示いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

2023/04/23 追記
実際の行列は以下のように作成しました。

```
sounds = AudioSegment.from_file('ファイル名.wav', 'wav')
sig = np.array(sounds.get_array_of_samples())[::sounds.channels]
a = sig[0:10]
```

wavファイルから作成した行列の10番目までの要素を抜き出しています。
その上で、以下３つのコードを試しました。

```
print(a ** 2)
print(pow(a, 2)))
print(np.power(a, 2))
```

しかし、いずれのコードも下の値が返ってきます。

```
[-22015  -3696  29732 -26471  27953  -5104  27113   5604   4081 -11551]
```

未熟な質問の仕方となり申し訳ありません。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「どのように作成したかは省略」は構わないけれど, 疑問点に関わるコードは試せるように質問内に記すのがよいでしょう (例えば `np.power(np.arange(10), 2)` などのように実際に動かせる・試せるコード)。

Comment: @oriri
情報が不足しており、ご迷惑をお掛けしております。
追記いたしましたのでご確認いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @huka さん、oririさんやmerinoさんは`a`のデータを抽出した処理ではなく、その抽出したデータを2乗するのにどのようなプログラムを作成(そして、どうやってそれが求めるものでは無いと判断)したのかを文章による説明ではなくソースコードはどのようなものか聞いているのだと思われます。

Comment: @kunif さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問の意図を読み取れていませんでした。修正いたします。

Comment: aは1次元のnumpy配列ですか？

Comment: `sounds.get_array_of_samples()` の戻り値は Python の built-in array 型なので、`numpy.ndarray` 型に変換する場合は一旦リストに変換するとよいかと思います。`sig = np.array(sounds.get_array_of_samples().tolist())[::sounds.channels]`

Comment: @merino
aは１次元です。

Comment: @metropolis 
リストに変換したところ、求めたい値が返ってきました！
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(既に回答あるけれど)
`.get_array_of_samples()` で得た arrayは
@merino 氏の回答にあるように 'h': signed short (2バイト) のようです

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("sample_data/test.wav")
arr = sound.get_array_of_samples()
display(type(song), type(arr))
# pydub.audio_segment.AudioSegment
# array.array

print(sound.array_type, arr.typecode)
# h h
```

そのまま演算すると, 場合によってはオーバーするので少し大きめの型への変換が必要
速度的には `np.int32` や `np.int64` がよいかも？

```py
import numpy as np
print(arr[:10])
display(np.array(arr[:10]) **2)   # ⇐ 二乗してもマイナスが現れる
display(np.array(arr[:10], dtype=np.int64) **2)
display(np.array(arr[:10].tolist()) **2)

# array('h', [-160, 107, 71, -491, 646, -161, -546, 752, -473, 324])
# array([ 25600,  11449,   5041, -21063,  24100,  25921, -29564, -24320,
#         27121, -26096], dtype=int16)
# array([ 25600,  11449,   5041, 241081, 417316,  25921, 298116, 565504,
#        223729, 104976])
# array([ 25600,  11449,   5041, 241081, 417316,  25921, 298116, 565504,
#        223729, 104976])


# 速度比較: 以下は Jupyterや colabで実行可能
%timeit np.array(arr, dtype=np.int64) **2
%timeit np.array(arr.tolist()) **2

# 5.76 µs ± 171 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 649 µs ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

`**`で出来ませんか。

```
a = np.array([-11007, -9748, -7942, -6331, -5511, -5508, -5421, -4330, -3289, -1807])
print(a ** 2)
# array([121154049,  95023504,  63075364,  40081561,  30371121,  30338064,
#         29387241,  18748900,  10817521,   3265249], dtype=int32)
```

上記のようにならないのであれば、質問の状況が再現するコードを提示してください。

---

【追記】
手元のwavファイルで質問のコードを試したところnumpy配列の型がint16になっていましたのでその型で表現できる範囲になってしまっていたのが、思った通りの計算結果にならなかった原因かと思います。

下記のようにすることでも計算できるかと思います。

```
print(a.astype(float) ** 2)
```

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
"a = np.array([-11007, -9748, -7942, -6331, -5511, -5508, -5421, -4330, -3289, -1807])"
確かにこのコードは正常に作動しました。
実際の行列となると上手くいかないようです。
情報が足りているか自信がないのですが、追記いたしましたのでご確認いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。